# Unable to resolve parse-react in React Native project

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, react-native, parse-react

I'm trying to include parse-react into my React Native project, but when running the app I'm getting the error in XCode and simulator:

> Unable to resolve module ./lib/react-native/ParseReact.js from /Users/Corey/Work/example_app/node_modules/parse-react/react-native.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/Corey/Work/example_app/node_modules/parse-react/lib/react-native/ParseReact.js and its parent directories

I've included the two packages as such:

```
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';
import ParseReact from 'parse-react/react-native';
```

Looking in the `node_modules/parse-react` folder, the `lib` directory doesn't contain a `react-native` directory, but it does have the `browser` directory.  I'm not sure if this is the problem or not, or how I'd go about getting that if it is.

I'm using react 0.14.7, react-native 0.21.0, parse 1.6.14, and parse-react 0.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I'm leaving my `package.json` here. Install accordingly, and you should be able to include parse modules into your project.

```
{
  "name": "commonDemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "parse": "^1.8.1",
    "parse-react": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native": "^0.20.0"
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works. Ideally, you should be able to include parse modules into your project using latest react-native release. But if using parse is absolutely necessary for your project, use this `package.json`.

To call `Parse.initialize()` use this-

`var Parse = require('parse/react-native');`

To call cloud functions and other functionality, use this-

`var ParseReact = require('parse/react-native').Parse;`

Comment: Thanks Mihir, I tried using your `package.json`, but still encountered the same issue.  I did *sort of* get around it (at least for the time being, this is by no means the long term solution) by cloning the current parse-react repo and running gulp to generate the `lib/react-native` directory, then added that to my project.

Comment: @Mihir it is `npm cache clean`

Comment: @neoDev You're right. I always forget this. It's `npm cache clean` indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the parse-react github README page.  It says it works with version 1.6.14 of parse.  It also says that 1.7 and 1.8 breaks compatibility. I had the same problem and downgrading to 1.6.14 solved the issue.

npm install parse@1.6.14 --save

Comment: Thanks for the replies @user3235983, and @Mihir.  I was (and still am) using parse 1.6.14.  I did upgrade to react-native 0.24.1 and now my `node_modules/parse-react/lib/react-native` directory does exists and everything is working correctly.  I can't say that nothing else changed in the meantime but it is working.